# ¿Como personalizar las esquinas de un borde?

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente código:

```css
#x{
  outline: 5px dashed grey;
  outline-offset: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
#y{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="x">
  <div id="y"></div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero es que el circulo morado se posicione en la esquina superior derecha del outline. Algo así como personalizar las equinas pero sin afectar al resto del outline, pero por desgracia no se me ocurre ninguna idea, si me pudieran ayudar sería de gran ayuda! Mil gracias!

PD:  Sin no entienden lo que quiero hacer díganmelo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes aplicarle la propiedad `margin` al círculo para mover su posición sin afectar a la esquina del cuadro rojo:

```css
#x{
  outline: 5px dashed grey;
  outline-offset: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
#y{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: -15px -15px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<br>
<div id="x">
  <div id="y"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

También puedes cambiar el tipo de posicionamiento:

```css
#x{
  outline: 5px dashed grey;
  outline-offset: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
#y{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: purple;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
  
  /* Puedes ajusarlo con un translate si lo necesitas */
  transform: translate(-1px, 1px);
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>

<div id="x">
  <div id="y"></div>
</div>
```